# Multiple input file loading to single mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am kind of new here. Have been searching for 2 days and no luck so I am posting my question here. Simply put I need to load data into a table in mysql. Now the thing is the input data for this table will be coming from two different source.

For eg: below is the how the 2 input files will be.

**Input_file1**

**Field**   Cust_ID1,   Acct_ID1,   MODIFIED,   Cust_Name,  Acct_name,  Comp_name1, Add2,   Comp_name2, Add4

**Sample value**    C1001,  A1001,  XXXXXX, JACK,   TIM KFC,    SINGAPORE,  YUM BRAND,  SINGAPORE

**Input_file2**

**Field**   ID, MODIFIEDBY, Ref_id, Sys_id

**Sample value**    3001,   TONY,   4001,   5001

Sorry was not able to copy data as in excel so improvised. The ',' is to show separate values. **Field** specifies the column name and its corresponding value is under **sample value**.

And the table that the above data needs to be loaded into is as such

**Sample _table_structure**

```
ID  
Cust_ID1    
Acct_ID1    
Ref_id  
Sys_id  
MODIFIED    
MODIFIEDBY  
Cust_Name   
Acct_name   
Comp_name1  
Add2    
Comp_name2  
Add4
```

What I need to do is load data into this table from the input data that comes to me in one single go. Is this possible. As you can see the order is also not a match that I can append and load it. Which is one main issue for me. 
And no, changing the input sequence is not a option. Data is huge so that will take too much effort. Any help with this I would appreciate. Also I would like to know if we could use a **shell** or **perl** script to do this.

Thanks in advance for the help & time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 load data local infile 'c:\\temp\\file.csv' 
into table table_name fields terminated by ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'  ignore 1 lines 
(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6,@col7,@col8,@col9)
set  Cust_ID1 = @col1,
 Acct_ID1 = @col2,
 MODIFIED =@col3,
 Cust_Name =@col4....;

load data local infile 'c:\\temp\\file2.csv' 
    into table table_name fields terminated by ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'  ignore 1 lines 
    (@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4 ) ## here Number the respective columns as per the table
    set  ID = @col1,
     MODIFIEDBY = @col2,
     REF_ID = @col3,
     sys_ID = @col4....
```

ID, MODIFIEDBY, Ref_id, Sys_id

same thing for csv file 2.
this way you can import file to table.
Note : 
Please save Excel file as csv format and then import

Comment: Whats the error ??
Please share...
Did you check on column numbers as suggested ??

Comment: sorry not able to post on comment so send as a answer.

Comment: hope u got a chance to take a look.

Comment: :- Sorry the earlier error if u read plz ignore. I was able to load the data as per your commands. But a question. Rite now i ran the above commands separately and they loaded data separately. that is now i have data from first file and den in next row data from second file. The columns have been loaded as i need. but it did not fill in the values of first sheet. Any suggestions